# Вывод и изменение данных mysql, не работает where id = $id

Tags: php, html, mysql

уважаемые разработчики и программисты!
Допустим, в базе mysql "elzamnbts" 3 записи. Вывел их в html форму этим кодом:

```
<td><?= $elzamnbts[1] ?><td>
  <td><select name="elzatext1">
    <option value="<?= $elzamnbts[2] ?>"><?= $elzamnbts[2] ?></option>                         
    <option value="Зарегистрирован">Зарегистрирован</option>
    <option value="Отложен">Отложен</option>
    <option value="В работу">В работу</option>
    <option value="В исполнении">В исполнении</option>
    <option value="Готов к выдаче">Готов к выдаче</option>
    
    </select></td>
     <td><select name="elzatext2">
    <option value="<?= $elzamnbts[3] ?>"><?= $elzamnbts[3] ?></option> 
    <option value="Не оплачен">Не оплачен</option> 
    <option value="Оплачен">Оплачен</option>
    </select></td>
     <td><select name="elzatext3">
    <option value="<?= $elzamnbts[4] ?>"><?= $elzamnbts[4] ?></option> 
    <option value="Обработка">Обработка</option> 
    <option value="Выдан">Выдан</option>
    </select></td>
    <button type="submit" class="mess">Сохранить
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при попытке сохранения данных после выбора пунктов select, данные не сохраняются. Код тут:

```
    <?php
    
    require_once '../config/connect.php';
    
    $id = $_POST['elza1_id'];
    $elza_stat1= $_POST['elzatext1'];
    $elza_stat2= $_POST['elzatext2'];
    $elza_stat3= $_POST['elzatext3'];
    
    
    mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE `elzamnbts` SET `elza_stat1` = '$elzatext1', 
`elza_stat2` = '$elzatext2', `elza_stat3` = '$elzatext3' WHERE `elzamnbts`.`elza1_id` = '$id'");
    
    header('Location: http://localhost/mnogbr/mnogbr1forman.php');
```

Проблема в определении места, в котором прошли изменения. Если убрать кусок `WHERE` elzamnbts`.`elza1_id `= '$id'"`, то изменяются данные во всей таблице - во всех трёх записях по указанным столбцам.
Если попытаться определить `elza1_id` = '$id'" - данные не сохраняются вовсе.
Если задать `elza1_id` = 3" (id через номер), то будут меняться значения в этой записи.

Вопрос - что вставить в where? Есть ли возможность отследить изменения в html форме (путём сравнения с изначальной версией/иными способами), чтобы затем вставить id, которые будут записываться.

Comment: выводи в три формы, а не в одну. И ради бога, используй подготовленные запросы, а не этот ужас.

Comment: В коде вы используете `$_POST['elza1_id']` но в html я не вижу упоминаний elza1_id, где определено ее значение ?  И да, стоит использовать подготовленные запросы https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php и печатать ошибки (собирая строку из переменных вы открываете огромную дыру для взлома вашего сайта, а не печатая ошибки не видите, что идет не так)

Comment: Благодарю, почитаю про запросы. В html выводится в первой строке (добавил). 
Что означает "выводи в три формы"? У меня есть одна форма, на которой можно будет поменять данные. Вопрос в том, как привязать id записи, чтобы внести изменения в БД.

Comment: выводи в три формы значит что у тебя должно быть **три формы, а не одна**